# CSV file is not recognized

Tags: r, excel

Im exporting an excel file into a .csv file (cause I want to import it into R) but R doesn't recognize it.

I think this is because when I open it in notepad I get:

```
Item;Description
1;ja
2;ne
```

While a file which does not have any import issues is structured like this in notepad:

```
"Item","Description"
"1","ja"
"2","ne"
```

Does anybody know how I can either export it from excel in the right format or import a csv file with ";" seperator into R.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to deal with semicolon-delimited files; you can use `read.csv2()` instead of `read.csv()` (although be aware this will also use comma as the decimal separator character!), or specify `sep=";"`.

Sorry to ask, but did you try reading `?read.csv` ?  The relevant information *is* in there, although it might admittedly be a little overwhelming/hard to sort out if you're new to R:

> sep: the field separator character.  Values on each line of the
>             file are separated by this character.  If ‘sep = ""’ (the
>             default for ‘read.table’) the separator is ‘white space’,
>             that is one or more spaces, tabs, newlines or carriage
>             returns.